# Migration: A class import is missing

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

Does anyone know about the following error?

> A class import is missing: You have a missing class import. Try
> importing this
>
> class: `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration`.

Comment: And if you import it like it says, does that correct it? Error messages are for reading, not just copying to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the your migration classes and make sure they all have this statement at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```